# Problem registering a generic type with DI .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, graphql

I'm trying to register some types used for graphql but I get an exception for a specific class that uses generics.
The class is defined like this:

```
public class ResponseGraphType<TGraphType, T> : ObjectGraphType<Response<T>> where TGraphType : GraphType
{
    public ResponseGraphType()
    {
...
```

And tried to register the class like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ResponseGraphType<,>), sp =>
{
    Type generic = typeof(ResponseGraphType<,>);
    Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType();
    return (GraphType)Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
});
```

But when I start the application I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.ResponseGraphType`2[TGraphType,T]' for service type 'GraphQL.Types.IProvideMetadata'.'

The IProvideMetadata is an interface implemented by

```
public class MetadataProvider : IProvideMetadata
... 
public interface IProvideMetadata
```

Any idea on how to register the `ResponseGraphType`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to register open-generic types using the lambda/delegate syntax. Only closed and non-generic service types can be registered using delegate. For open-generic types you need to depend on the Auto-Wiring registration syntax, meaning you should do the following:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(ResponseGraphType<,>), typeof(ResponseGraphType<,>));
```

With this registration you instruct MS.DI to compose and return the appropriate closed version of `ResponseGraphType<TGraphType, T>` in case the user requests that closed version of `ResponseGraphType<TGraphType, T>`.

Comment: thanks, I've tried registering like that but still getting the same error

Comment: In the context of your question, the error makes little sense to me. You are likely missing some essential information in your question. Please convert your question into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the full exception details (message and stack trace of the exception and *all* its inner exceptions).